# Why is this Transpose() required in my WorldViewProj matrix?

Tags: matrix, direct3d, matrix-multiplication, hlsl

Given a super-basic vertex shader such as:

```
output.position = mul(position, _gWorldViewProj);
```

I was having a great deal of trouble because I was setting _gWorldViewProj as follows; I tried both (a bit of flailing) to make sure it wasn't just backwards.

```
mWorldViewProj = world * view * proj;
mWorldViewProj = proj * view * world;
```

My solution turned out to be:

```
mWorldView = mWorld * mView;
mWorldViewProj = XMMatrixTranspose(worldView * proj);
```

Can someone explain why this XMMatrixTranspose was required?  I know there were matrix differences between XNA and HLSL (I think) but not between vanilla C++ and HLSL, though I could be wrong.

Problem is I don't know if I'm wrong or what I'm wrong about!  So if someone could tell me precisely why the transpose is required, I hopefully won't make the same mistake again.

Comment: Can you explain what the symptoms were that led you to believe you needed to transpose the matrix?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the CPU, 2D arrays are generally stored in row-major ordering, so the order in memory goes `x[0][0]`, `x[0][1]`, ...  In HLSL, matrix declarations default to [column-major ordering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509634(v=vs.85).aspx#Matrix_Ordering), so the order goes `x[0][0]`, `x[1][0]`, ...

In order to transform the memory from the format defined on the CPU to the order expected in HLSL, you need to transpose the CPU matrix before sending it to the GPU. Alternatively, you can `row_major` keyword in HLSL to declare the matrices as row major, eliminating the need for a transpose but leading to different codegen in HLSL (you'll often end up with mul-adds instead of dot-products).

Comment: So is it correct to say that any time I'm taking an XMMATRIX and storing it in a float4x4 constant buffer, I -always- need to transpose it first?

Comment: @Dave Usually, but not necessarily.  By convention, most math libraries (e.g. XNAMath / DirectXMath) will generate row-major matrix data, so when the library generates the projection matrix, it'll be in row-major and need to be transposed.  But you could also have the library output in a column-major format, eliminating the need for a transpose.  Keep in mind you should only ever need at most one transpose operation, at the point just before uploading to the constant buffer - don't transpose intermediate matrices on the CPU.

Comment: HLSL doesn't require it, it just defaults to column-major. This is covered explicitly in the *DirectXMath Programmer's Guide* in the **Working with D3DXMath** section under Using DirectXMath with Direct3D and a link to the related [HLSL docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509634.aspx#Matrix_Ordering). In short: DirectXMath supports either left- or right-handed viewing coordinates, but all matrices are row-major. You can tell HLSL to use row-major, but it defaults to column-major which is slightly faster. Hence the transpose just before setting a CB.